# How to actually plot a sample tree from randomForest::getTree()?

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-forest, cart

Anyone got library or code suggestions on how to actually **plot a couple of sample trees** from:

```
getTree(rfobj, k, labelVar=TRUE)
```

(Yes I know you're not supposed to do this operationally, RF is a blackbox, etc etc. I want to visually sanity-check a tree to see if any variables are behaving counterintuitively, need tweaking/combining/discretization/transformation, check how well my encoded factors are working, etc.)

---

Prior questions without a decent answer:

- [How to make Random Forests more interpretable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32125/how-to-make-random-forests-more-interpretable)
- Also [Obtaining knowledge from a random forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/obtaining-knowledge-from-a-random-forest)

I actually want to **plot a sample tree**. So don't argue with me about that, already. I'm not asking about `varImpPlot`(Variable Importance Plot) or `partialPlot` or `MDSPlot`, or [these other plots](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/images.php?show=all&query=package:randomForest), I already have those, but they're not a substitute for seeing a sample tree.
Yes I can visually inspect the output of `getTree(...,labelVar=TRUE)`.

(I guess a `plot.rf.tree()` contribution would be very-well-received.)

Comment: I don't see a need to be preemptively argumentative, especially if you are asking for someone to volunteer to help you; it doesn't come across well. CV has an etiquette policy--you may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @gung: every previous question on this topic has decayed into people insisting that it was not necessary, and indeed heretical, to plot a sample tree. Read the citations I gave. I'm looking for a sketch here of how to code plotting an rf tree.

Comment: I see some answers where users are trying to be helpful & address the question, along w/ some comments questioning the premise of the idea (which, I honestly believe, are intended in a helpful spirit as well). It's certainly possible to acknowledge that some people will disagree w/o being testy.

Comment: I see zero answers where anyone has ever plotted a tree, in over a year. I'm looking for a specific answer to that specific question.

Comment: It is possible to plot a single tree built with `cforest` (in the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package). Otherwise, you'll have to convert the `data.frame` returned by `randomForest::getTree` to a `tree`-like object.

Comment: @chl : please make that an answer. Where is the spec for a `tree` object? Are there any helper libraries (`as.tree`)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**First (and easiest) solution:** If you are not keen to stick with classical RF, as implemented in Andy Liaw's `randomForest`, you can try the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package which provides a different implementation of the original RF algorithm (use of conditional trees and aggregation scheme based on units weight average). Then, as reported on this [R-help post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328023656/https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-Fwd-Re-Party-extract-BinaryTree-from-cforest-td3878100.html), you can plot a single member of the list of trees. It seems to run smoothly, as far as I can tell. Below is a plot of one tree generated by `cforest(Species ~ ., data=iris, controls=cforest_control(mtry=2, mincriterion=0))`.

[image]

**Second (almost as easy) solution:** Most of tree-based techniques in R (`tree`, `rpart`, `TWIX`, etc.) offers a `tree`-like structure for printing/plotting a single tree. The idea would be to convert the output of `randomForest::getTree` to such an R object, even if it is nonsensical from a statistical point of view. Basically,  it is easy to access the tree structure from a `tree` object, as shown below. Please note that it will slightly differ depending of the type of task--regression vs. classification--where in the later case it will add class-specific probabilities as the last column of the `obj$frame` (which is a `data.frame`).

```
> library(tree)
> tr <- tree(Species ~ ., data=iris)
> tr
node), split, n, deviance, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 150 329.600 setosa ( 0.33333 0.33333 0.33333 )  
   2) Petal.Length < 2.45 50   0.000 setosa ( 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000 ) *
   3) Petal.Length > 2.45 100 138.600 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.50000 0.50000 )  
     6) Petal.Width < 1.75 54  33.320 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.90741 0.09259 )  
      12) Petal.Length < 4.95 48   9.721 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.97917 0.02083 )  
        24) Sepal.Length < 5.15 5   5.004 versicolor ( 0.00000 0.80000 0.20000 ) *
        25) Sepal.Length > 5.15 43   0.000 versicolor ( 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 ) *
      13) Petal.Length > 4.95 6   7.638 virginica ( 0.00000 0.33333 0.66667 ) *
     7) Petal.Width > 1.75 46   9.635 virginica ( 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826 )  
      14) Petal.Length < 4.95 6   5.407 virginica ( 0.00000 0.16667 0.83333 ) *
      15) Petal.Length > 4.95 40   0.000 virginica ( 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 ) *
> tr$frame
            var   n        dev       yval splits.cutleft splits.cutright yprob.setosa yprob.versicolor yprob.virginica
1  Petal.Length 150 329.583687     setosa          <2.45           >2.45   0.33333333       0.33333333      0.33333333
2        <leaf>  50   0.000000     setosa                                  1.00000000       0.00000000      0.00000000
3   Petal.Width 100 138.629436 versicolor          <1.75           >1.75   0.00000000       0.50000000      0.50000000
6  Petal.Length  54  33.317509 versicolor          <4.95           >4.95   0.00000000       0.90740741      0.09259259
12 Sepal.Length  48   9.721422 versicolor          <5.15           >5.15   0.00000000       0.97916667      0.02083333
24       <leaf>   5   5.004024 versicolor                                  0.00000000       0.80000000      0.20000000
25       <leaf>  43   0.000000 versicolor                                  0.00000000       1.00000000      0.00000000
13       <leaf>   6   7.638170  virginica                                  0.00000000       0.33333333      0.66666667
7  Petal.Length  46   9.635384  virginica          <4.95           >4.95   0.00000000       0.02173913      0.97826087
14       <leaf>   6   5.406735  virginica                                  0.00000000       0.16666667      0.83333333
15       <leaf>  40   0.000000  virginica                                  0.00000000       0.00000000      1.00000000
```

Then, there are methods for pretty printing and plotting those objects. The key functions are a generic `tree:::plot.tree` method (I put a triple `:` which allows you to view the code in R directly) relying on `tree:::treepl` (graphical display) and `tree:::treeco` (compute nodes coordinates). These functions expect the `obj$frame` representation of the tree. Other subtle issues: (1) the argument `type = c("proportional", "uniform")` in the default plotting method, `tree:::plot.tree`, help to manage vertical distance between nodes (`proportional` means it is proportional to deviance, `uniform` mean it is fixed); (2) you need to complement `plot(tr)` by a call to `text(tr)` to add text labels to nodes and splits, which in this case means that you will also have to take a look at `tree:::text.tree`.

The `getTree` method from `randomForest` returns a different structure, which is documented in the online help. A typical output is shown below, with terminal nodes indicated by `status` code (-1). (Again, output will differ depending on the type of task, but only on the `status` and `prediction` columns.)

```
> library(randomForest)
> rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
> getTree(rf, 1, labelVar=TRUE)
   left daughter right daughter    split var split point status prediction
1              2              3 Petal.Length        4.75      1       <NA>
2              4              5 Sepal.Length        5.45      1       <NA>
3              6              7  Sepal.Width        3.15      1       <NA>
4              8              9  Petal.Width        0.80      1       <NA>
5             10             11  Sepal.Width        3.60      1       <NA>
6              0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1  virginica
7             12             13  Petal.Width        1.90      1       <NA>
8              0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1     setosa
9             14             15  Petal.Width        1.55      1       <NA>
10             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1 versicolor
11             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1     setosa
12            16             17 Petal.Length        5.40      1       <NA>
13             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1  virginica
14             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1 versicolor
15             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1  virginica
16             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1 versicolor
17             0              0         <NA>        0.00     -1  virginica
```

If you can manage to convert the above table to the one generated by `tree`, you will probably be able to customize `tree:::treepl`, `tree:::treeco` and `tree:::text.tree` to suit your needs, though I do not have an example of this approach. In particular, you probably want to get rid of the use of deviance, class probabilities, etc. which are not meaningful in RF. All you want is to set up nodes coordinates and split values. You could use `fixInNamespace()` for that, but, to be honest, I'm not sure this is the right way to go.

**Third (and certainly clever) solution:** Write a true `as.tree` helper
function which will alleviates all of the above "patches". You could then use R's plotting methods or, probably better, [Klimt](http://rosuda.org/software/KLIMT/) (directly from R) to display individual trees.

Answer (score 52):

I'm four years late, but if you really want to stick to the `randomForest` package (and there are some good reasons to do so), and want to actually visualize the tree, you can use the [***reprtree***](https://github.com/araastat/reprtree) package.

The package is not super well documented (you can find the docs [here](https://github.com/araastat/reprtree/tree/master/man)), but everything is pretty straightforward. To install the package refer to [initialize.R](https://github.com/araastat/reprtree/blob/master/initialize.R) in the repo, so simply run the following:

```
options(repos='http://cran.rstudio.org')
have.packages <- installed.packages()
cran.packages <- c('devtools','plotrix','randomForest','tree')
to.install <- setdiff(cran.packages, have.packages[,1])
if(length(to.install)>0) install.packages(to.install)

library(devtools)
if(!('reprtree' %in% installed.packages())){
   install_github('munoztd0/reprtree')
}
for(p in c(cran.packages, 'reprtree')) eval(substitute(library(pkg), list(pkg=p)))
```

Then go ahead and make your model and tree:

```
library(randomForest)
library(reprtree)

model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE, ntree=500, mtry = 2, do.trace=100)

reprtree:::plot.getTree(model)
```

And there you go! Beautiful and simple.

[image: tree generated from plot.getTree(model)]

You can check the github repo to learn about the other methods in the package. In fact, if you check [plot.getTree.R](https://github.com/araastat/reprtree/blob/master/R/plot.getTree.R), you'll notice that the author uses his own implementation of `as.tree()` which [chl♦](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/930/chl) suggested you could build yourself in his answer. This means that you could do this:

```
tree <- getTree(model, k=1, labelVar=TRUE)
realtree <- reprtree:::as.tree(tree, model)
```

And then potentially use `realtree` with other tree plotting packages such as [tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still happily accepting answers, this seems to be an area where people are dissatistified with the offerings. I guess the new new thing would be to support `xgboost` too.

Comment: no problem. It took me hours to find the library/package so I figured that if not useful to you, it would be to other people trying to draw trees while still sticking to the `randomForest` package.

Comment: No, that's awesome @jgozal. I can't understand why things are so fragmented.

Comment: Cool finding. Note: It plots the representative tree, in some sense, the tree in the ensemble which are on average the "closest" to all the other trees in the ensemble

Comment: @Chris The function `plot.getTree()` plots an individual tree.  The function `plot.reprtree()` in that package plots a representative tree.

Comment: I tried to install it and got this error: Error: C:/Temp/RtmpeIA1Ui/devtools21204b0472f5/araastat-reprtree-5cff507/man/text.tree.Rd:41: Bad \link text

Comment: @raphael75 can you try running the install script on my answer as opposed to the one in the repo that's referenced? there are a few subtle differences

Comment: i got model from caret and want to feed into reptree with `reprtree:::plot.getTree(mod_rf_1$finalModel)`, however, there's an "Error in data.frame(var = fr$var, splits = as.character(gTree[, "split point"]),  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 2631, 0"

Comment: I am unable to install reprtree as well: Error: C:/Users/vipin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpM9fHUZ/devtools1778ab76a54/araastat-reprtree-5cff507/man/text.tree.Rd:41: Bad \link text
* removing 'C:/Users/vipin/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/reprtree'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: FYI: reprtree:::plot.getTree() seems not to wor k if the random forest is generated using the alternative way e.g. randomForest(iris[,-5], iris[,5])

Comment: Any issue that is directly related to the library/package should be directed to the author. Please open an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/araastat/reprtree/issues

Comment: For now, `reprtree` isn't supported by R >= 3.6. I found a workaround by cloning the repo, sourcing all the files into R, and calling the function from my global environment. `lapply(list.files("C:/Users/rpauloo/Documents/GitHub/reprtree/R"), source)`.

Answer (score 16):

I've created some functions to extract the rules of a tree.

```
#***********************
#return the rules of a tree
#***********************
getConds<-function(tree){
  #store all conditions into a list
  conds<-list()
  #start by the terminal nodes and find previous conditions
  id.leafs<-which(tree$status==-1)
   j<-0
   for(i in id.leafs){
  j<-j+1
  prevConds<-prevCond(tree,i)
  conds[[j]]<-prevConds$cond
  while(prevConds$id>1){
    prevConds<-prevCond(tree,prevConds$id)
    conds[[j]]<-paste(conds[[j]]," & ",prevConds$cond)
        }
  if(prevConds$id==1){
   conds[[j]]<-paste(conds[[j]]," => ",tree$prediction[i])
    }
    
  }
  
  return(conds)
}

#**************************
#find the previous conditions in the tree
#**************************
prevCond<-function(tree,i){
  if(i %in% tree$right_daughter){
  id<-which(tree$right_daughter==i)
  cond<-paste(tree$split_var[id],">",tree$split_point[id])
   }
   if(i %in% tree$left_daughter){
    id<-which(tree$left_daughter==i)
  cond<-paste(tree$split_var[id],"<",tree$split_point[id])
  }
  
  return(list(cond=cond,id=id))
}

#remove spaces in a word
collapse<-function(x){
  x<-sub(" ","_",x)
  
  return(x)
}


data(iris)
require(randomForest)
mod.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
tree<-getTree(mod.rf, k=1, labelVar=TRUE)
#rename the name of the column
colnames(tree)<-sapply(colnames(tree),collapse)
rules<-getConds(tree)
print(rules)
```