# In a single random forest tree, what does the "p < .001" represent in the nodes

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-forest

Hack-R's answer (the first one) to this question:

[How to actually plot a sample tree from randomForest::getTree()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree)

shows a plot for a single binary decision tree in a random forest. I was wondering what the "p<0.001" represents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the random forest algorithm being used is based on a conditional inference framework (rather than Breiman's original algorithm). It essentially determines whether a split should be carried out by using a p-value calculated from a permutation test, corrected for multiple comparisons. The main benefit of this approach over Breiman's is that conditional inference forests yield unbiased variable importance metrics. It's available in R using the [party](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package, and you can read more about it [here](http://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Hothorn+Hornik+Zeileis-2006.pdf).