# understanding random forest tree plot

Tags: random-forest

I would like to understand the randomforest tree plot in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer.

The conditions and logic on each branch of the tree are very straightforward. But what does the content in the grey boxes at the end of the tree mean? Considering there are 3 species in the iris dataset, how do I know which of the species is actually being predicted according to the conditions in the branches?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the three probabilities of belonging to each of the classes. They are estimated by the fraction of records with this class in the leaf.

It is strange that it says n=0 though

Comment: how do you know which probability belongs to each class?

Comment: I also get n = 0 in my own models with a fairly different dataset