# Visualizing C5.0 Decision Tree?

Tags: r, data-visualization, cart

Is there a direct way to visualize a c5.0 decision tree? Here my code:

```
library(C50)
data(churn)
myTree = C5.0(x = churnTrain[, -20], y = churnTrain$churn)
summary(myTree)
```

I am getting a long list of C5.0 objects from a program that I do not control but I could convert it into something else if that is absolutely necessary. Any ideas/pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful, but I'm not sure. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/obtaining-knowledge-from-a-random-forest

Answer (score 8):

I might be missing something in your question but simply

```
plot(myTree)
```

gives you a visualization of the tree (based on the infrastructure in `partykit`)

[image: C5.0 tree]

Of course the tree is very large and you either need to zoom into the image or use a large screen to read it...

You can also use `partykit` to just display subtrees. For example if you want to just show the left branch below the root (starting from node 2) and the right branch below the root (starting from node 33) you could do:

```
library("partykit")
myTree2 <- C50:::as.party.C5.0(myTree)
plot(myTree2[2])
plot(myTree2[33])
```