# How to extract a splitting point for numerical values in a random forest model?

Tags: random-forest

I have a dataset including discrete and continuous variables on which I ran a random forest model using the r-package `randomForest`. I have read several times that the output of a RF model is a "black box".

I know that I can actually get the splitting points of the numerical values by tree. However, I would like to know, if I could extract a "representative" splitting point which I could use, in general (not specific to only 1tree).

Comment: Of interest: [Obtaining knowledge from a random forest](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21152/7290).

Answer (score 1):

Not really. All splits after the first are conditional on the previous splits, so even if you only look at splits on some variable, it doesn't have the same meaning -- it's the difference between $X|Y$ and $X|Z$ etc. Imagine that you're classifying points in a circle like in [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/can-random-forest-be-used-for-feature-selection-in-multiple-linear-regression/164068#164068). If you're examining $x_1$, sometimes you split near 1 and sometimes near -1, but it's going to be hard to make sense of that out of context. @gung's suggestion to look at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21152/7290) is a good one.